# Declare ImageButton for use in function

Tags: android, function, button

I'm programming a Google Maps app and I'm trying to implement a image Button that changes the map type from normal to hybrid.

I declare my button in the onCreate instance:

```
    ImageButton changeBtn =(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.changeBtn);
    changeBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            changeMapType();
        }
    });
```

And here's my function changeMapType(); :

```
    private void changeMapType(){
    if(MapTypeInt == 0){
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        changeBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.satellite);
        MapTypeInt = 1;
    } else if (MapTypeInt == 1) {
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        changeBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.normal_map);
        MapTypeInt = 0;
    }
}
```

Now to the problem, I cant use the imageButton "changeBtn" outside of the onCreate instance, and when i declare the button at the top of my program code it causes the program to crash. Does anyone have a solution to this?

Logcat when declared in class level:

```
01-10 10:22:00.555: E/AndroidRuntime(2872): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-10 10:22:00.555: E/AndroidRuntime(2872): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.androidbasic12/com.example.androidbasic12.map}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-10 10:22:00.555: E/AndroidRuntime(2872):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2106)
01-10 10:22:00.555: E/AndroidRuntime(2872):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
01-10 10:22:00.555: E/AndroidRuntime(2872):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
01-10 10:22:00.555: E/AndroidRuntime(2872):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
01-10 10:22:00.555: E/AndroidRuntime(2872):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-10 10:22:00.555: E/AndroidRuntime(2872):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-10 10:22:00.555: E/AndroidRuntime(2872):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
01-10 10:22:00.555: E/AndroidRuntime(2872):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-10 10:22:00.555: E/AndroidRuntime(2872):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-10 10:22:00.555: E/AndroidRuntime(2872):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-10 10:22:00.555: E/AndroidRuntime(2872):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-10 10:22:00.555: E/AndroidRuntime(2872):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-10 10:22:00.555: E/AndroidRuntime(2872): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-10 10:22:00.555: E/AndroidRuntime(2872):     at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1839)
01-10 10:22:00.555: E/AndroidRuntime(2872):     at com.example.androidbasic12.map.<init>(map.java:24)
01-10 10:22:00.555: E/AndroidRuntime(2872):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
01-10 10:22:00.555: E/AndroidRuntime(2872):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
01-10 10:22:00.555: E/AndroidRuntime(2872):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
01-10 10:22:00.555: E/AndroidRuntime(2872):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
01-10 10:22:00.555: E/AndroidRuntime(2872):     ... 11 more
```

And the code when i try to declare it at class level:

```
public class map extends FragmentActivity{
private static final LatLng SYDNEY = new LatLng(-33.88,151.21);
public static final LatLng sala = new LatLng(59.91602, 16.594108);
int travel = 0;
int MapTypeInt = 0;
private GoogleMap mMap;
GoogleMapOptions options = new GoogleMapOptions();
ImageButton changeBtn =(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.changeBtn);
```

Comment: Why does it crash? Can you post the log?

Comment: When i declare the button at class level, it crashes and gives this logcat

Comment: Sorry, i was gona post it in comments but i messed it up, now its there.

Comment: How are you declaring it outside of `onCreate`?  You should not attempt to assign to it, just declare, and keep the assignment in `onCreate`.

Comment: I belive that what produces this error is "  ImageButton changeBtn =(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.changeBtn);" . Look again in your xml file and check if you really have that component . Maybe you declared it as Button or you did not set your correct layout .

Comment: I edited the question with how i tried to declare it outside of `onCreate`, I know the button works when i declare it as normal in `onCreate`.

Comment: Sorry guys, this problem was just me being a newbie programmer. I declared the button as normal in `onCreate`. Then in the function i added ImageButton button like this: `private void changeMapType(ImageButton button){
  "rest of function code" } `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you declare the button outside onCreate, you cannot assign it. You should assign it in onCreate as:

```
changeBtn =(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.changeBtn);
```

Then you can use changeBtn in the function.
Since findViewById mustn't be used before  setContentView.